# Date_format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I have a column named start_date.
eg:

[image]

I want to get the difference in days from the start_date to the end of the year.

In MySQL, this helps `DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%Y-12-31'),start_date)`

How can I get achieve this in the **SQL server**?

Comment: what is the data type for the column ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATEDIFF()` function to get the difference in days and `DATEFROMPARTS()` to get the last day of the year:

```
select start_date,
  datediff(day, start_date, datefromparts(year(start_date), 12, 31)) diff
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=313302fc9c5d8fcd7d3b5ebd44607627).
Results:

```
> start_date | diff
> :--------- | ---:
> 2019-01-25 |  340
> 2018-12-01 |   30
> 2019-12-01 |   30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
start_date,
cast(DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, start_date) +1, 0))as date)end_date,
datediff(day, start_date, DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, start_date) +1, 0))) diff
from tablename
```

[image: result]